# matlab improfile for scaled images

Tags: image, matlab

i have images that are shown using `imagesc(xxx,yyy,matrix)`, created by a function and returned as an image handle, say `pic=plot_one(38)` (38 is image number).

The image is scaled so that using `get(pic,'XData')` gives a vector of size 50, starting at -87.4 and ending in 0, and so for `YData`, 175 length vector starting at -128 and ending at 128.

I'm trying to use improfile(xdata,ydata,pic,...) to find a profile in the image. i tried few options for defining the end points [x1,x2],[y1,y2] but none succeeded. i only got NANs.

here's a code for example:

```
  pic = plot_one(38);

  xd=get(pic,'xdata');

  yd=get(pic,'ydata');

  [sx,sy,s]=improfile(xd,yd,pic,[xd(1),xd(end)],[yd(1),yd(1)]);
```

s is just NANs.
(plot_one returnes an image, meaning in it there's "res=imagesc(xxx,yyy,...)")

how do i use that option properly?

thanks in advance!

Ariel

Comment: Could you provide some code? At this time, it is very tough to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
I gave improfile an image handle instead of a matrix, so it tried to compute profile of a 1X1 matrix